# Cointegration (different coefficients using VECM /ca.jo and p-values)

Tags: r, p-value, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

I am trying to get the p-values of my **cointegrating vector**. I read many questions about it and most of the answers relies on `ca.jo` funtion from `urca` package (Bernhard Pfaff´s book -page 156- is one reference). So, I decided to try it (I am using exogenous variables for the short run so `tsDyn` package was my best choice since user can set up this easily).

The following is the function I used in `VECM` (tsDyn). Please, note I excluded exogenous variables:

```
X = VECM(sub_target_1, lag=3, r=1, include="const", estim="ML", LRinclude="const")
```

these are my results:

```
#############
###Model VECM 
#############
Full sample size: 431   End sample size: 427
Number of variables: 4  Number of estimated slope parameters 52
AIC -15665.99   BIC -15442.86   SSR 1.146335
Cointegrating vector (estimated by ML):
   Clp_Fx_Nom      Copper       Oil    Ratio     const
r1          1 -0.03725038 0.1276867 1.018937 -8.932703


                    ECT                Clp_Fx_Nom -1       Copper -1          
Equation Clp_Fx_Nom 0.0042(0.0173)     -0.0316(0.0568)     -0.0427(0.0258).   
Equation Copper     0.0249(0.0379)     -0.2829(0.1244)*    -0.1045(0.0565).
```

This is the function `ca.jo` (urca):

```
test=ca.jo(sub_target_1, type="trace",K=3,ecdet="const", spec="longrun")
```

and these were the results:

```
###################### 
# Johansen-Procedure # 
###################### 

Test type: trace statistic , without linear trend and constant in cointegration 

Eigenvalues (lambda):
[1]  9.466481e-02  2.847656e-02  1.536945e-02  9.699295e-03 -2.795648e-18

Values of teststatistic and critical values of test:

          test 10pct  5pct  1pct
r <= 3 |  4.17  7.52  9.24 12.97
r <= 2 | 10.80 17.85 19.96 24.60
r <= 1 | 23.17 32.00 34.91 41.07
r = 0  | 65.73 49.65 53.12 60.16

Eigenvectors, normalised to first column:
(These are the cointegration relations)

              Clp_Fx_Nom.l3   Copper.l3     Oil.l3   Ratio.l3   constant
Clp_Fx_Nom.l3    1.00000000   1.0000000  1.0000000   1.000000   1.000000
Copper.l3       -0.03333813   0.5059200  0.3900929  12.301568   2.931141
Oil.l3           0.11958746  -0.2209898  0.2773398   2.166322  -1.252026
Ratio.l3         1.03753074   1.2162162 -0.2086412 -17.503155 -10.584605
constant        -8.96705858 -11.0296017 -9.3375875 -45.202912   6.269255
```

As you can see, the results are slightly different. I would like to understand why is that. Am I missing something when I set up one of them?

Additionaly, how I can find the p-values using inputs just from `VECM` (tsDyn package)?

Answer (score 0):

In VECM you must specify the order of the VEC, that is, lag = p-1 where p is the order of the VAR.(You can get the order of the VAR by information criteria using the VARselect function)

In ca.jo you must enter K = p (order of the VAR)

```
test=ca.jo(sub_target_1, type="trace",K=3,ecdet="const", spec="longrun")

cajorls(test,r=1)

X = VECM(sub_target_1, lag=3-1, r=1, include="const", estim="ML", LRinclude="const")
```

With these specs you should have the same results.